# NotificationCenter observers are not receiving posts

Tags: swift, swift3, nsnotificationcenter

I have been trying for many hours to get notification posts to be received by an observer, but it has been failing me every time I try. I put the observer into my root view controller with is an embedded tab controller and tried to get one of the tab controllers to send a post for it to receive, but to no avail. I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out, and I'd really like to because notifications could be so freaking useful!

Here's my code:

**ViewController**

```
let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue:"categoryChange")

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(forName:myNotification, object:"test", queue:nil, using:test)
}

func test(notification:Notification) -> Void {
    print("Yo")
}
```

And here's my **DashboardController**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue:"categoryChange")
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.post(name:myNotification,
            object: nil,
            userInfo:["message":"Hello there!"])
}
```

I have tried putting the observer into the init, `viewDidLoad`, and `viewDidAppear` while the post is in the `viewDidLoad`, and I did the vice versa. Nothing has worked so far, and I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Are you testing in Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0?

Comment: just check if you are posting notification before you add observer?

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma Yeah, I'm testing it in Xcode 8 with Swift 3.0

Comment: @NikhilManapure I did, I placed breakpoints to make sure that upon starting the application that the observer was placed before the post and it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you are passing `test` (as `String`) with `object` parameter when you adding observer in `NotificationCenter`.

**(From Documentation) object:**

> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>
> If you pass nil, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.

So it is the reason your notification is not getting called because you are not posting notification with the help of that `object`, simply set `object` to `nil` will works for you.

```
nc.addObserver(forName:myNotification, object:nil, queue:nil, using:test)
```

Comment: This worked for me! I can't believe it was something so simple; that's always the case! Thank you, so much!

Comment: So if he placed `"test"` in the `object` of the post then will he recieve the notification?

Comment: @Nick Welcome mate :)

Comment: @ZonilyJame Not with the `String` for that you need to use reference type object, like `self` represent the current controller and when you post notification you need the reference of that controller that you have added as Object.

Answer (score 3):

It works in my project.

**Post Notification**

```
 let dic: [String:AnyObject] = ["news_id": 1 as AnyObject,"language_id" : 2 as AnyObject]
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationKeyIndentifier"), object: dic)
```

**Notification Observer**

```
          override func viewDidLoad() {
              super.viewDidLoad()
              NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handlePushNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationKeyIndentifier"), object: nil)
          }
         func handlePushNotification(notification: NSNotification){

            if let dic = notification.object as? [String: AnyObject]{

                if let language_id = dic["language_id"] as? Int{

                    if let news_id = dic["news_id"] as? Int{
                        print(language_id)
                        print(news_id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer is along the same lines as Nirav; I wish I could accept two answers because they both accomplish the same thing in general; his explains why it wasn't working, yours explains how to implement a solution that I need.